# How can I change the filewriting function so it writes ";" instead of "," when it's inside of "(" ")"?

Tags: python, file-writing

This is what my function is writting:

```
Marianne Thibault, french, ('phones',), 11:09, 230
```

This is what I want it to write:

```
Marianne Thibault, french, (phones; computers), 11:09, 230
```

This is the function I am using:

```
 header='\n'.join(header)
        out_file=open(file_name,'w')
        out_file.write(str(header)+ '\n')
        out_file.write('Operators:'+'\n')
        for i in range(len(operators)):
                out_file.write(', '.join(map(str, operators[i])))
                out_file.write('\n')
        out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join(header))
    out_file.write('\nOperators:\n')
    for operator in operators:
        formatted_fields = []
        for field in operator:
            if isinstance(field, tuple):
                semi_delimited_field = '; '.join(str(x) for x in field)
                field_in_parens = '(' + semi_delimited_field + ')'
                formatted_fields.append(field_in_parens)
            else:
                formatted_fields.append(str(field))
        out_file.write(', '.join(formatted_fields))
        out_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: The problem now is that I don't want the parentheses to be gone, I've tried putting them on again but I can't seem to do it.

Comment: @Nypt008: You just need to wrap the formatted field in parentheses. I updated the example to show it.